# Pygame TypeError: invalid destination position for blit

Tags: python, pygame, blit

I'm starting to learn pygame and today I get "TypeError: invalid destination position for blit" and I don't know how to repair my code. If someone know where I missed, please help me!
Python says me that error is somewhere in this fragment:

```
    def __init__(self,img,x,y,width,height,speed):
        sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = transform.scale(image.load(img), (width, height))
        self.height=height
        self.width=width
        self.speed=speed
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x=x
        self.rect.y=y
    def reset(self,player):
        if player.rect.x>4*tiles:
            if player.rect.y > 4*tiles:
                window.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x), self.rect.y - (player.rect.y - tiles*4))
            else:
                window.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x - (player.rect.x - tiles*4), self.rect.y))
        else:
            if player.rect.y > 4*tiles:
                window.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y - (player.rect.y - tiles*4)))
            else:
                window.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
```

and in this:

```
    time.Clock().tick(144)
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            exit()
    for wall in list_wall:
        wall.reset(player)
    for floor in list_floor:
        floor.reset(player)
    player.control()
    if player.rect.x>=4*tiles:
        if player.rect.y >= 4*tiles:
            window.blit(player.image, (player.rect.x - (player.rect.x - tiles*4), player.rect.y))
        else:
            window.blit(player.image, (player.rect.x, player.rect.y)) 
    else:
        if player.rect.y >= 4*tiles:
            window.blit(player.image, (player.rect.x, player.rect.y - (player.rect.y - tiles*4)))
        else:
            window.blit(player.image, (player.rect.x, player.rect.y))
    window.blit(player.image, (player.rect.x, player.rect.y))
    enemy1.reset(player)
    enemy1.control()
    display.flip()
```

Thank you

Comment: In which line is the error. Please shoe the complete error trace!

Comment: There is a typo in your code. `window.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x), self.rect.y - (player.rect.y - tiles*4))` must be `window.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y - (player.rect.y - tiles*4)))` Focus on the parentheses.

Comment: ... `blit(image, (x, y))`

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your code. `window.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x), self.rect.y - (player.rect.y - tiles*4))` must be `window.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y - (player.rect.y - tiles*4)))`.
Focus on the parentheses. It is `blit(image, (x, y))`.